# Python SMTP other than localhost

Tags: python, email, smtp

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

in the `s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')` do i have to setup something in order to work.. like stmp server?

if so how do i do that? anyone know if i can use smtp server other than localhost? gmail smtp server doesnt work for me because it has to go through gmail api and it cant send email as arbritary emails

[EDIT]

`s = smtplib.SMTP('mail')` works for me
anyone know what stmp server `'mail'` refers to?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use gmail smtp server

Comment: @WalidSaad i cant send email as someone other than the email that have enabled Gmail API (or alias). I need to be able to send emails as multiple different addreses

Comment: How to set up an SMTP server is not a programming question.  You may have better luck over at [Server Fault](//serverfault.com/); however, before posting there, please check their posting guidelines, and look for duplicates of your question.

Comment: @tripleee My judgement told me this leans towards as a programming question. i was asking to clarify the how the python smtplib code works. The tutorial/doc would  just say localhost without explaining what about localhost the stmplib is using/depending

Answer (score 2):

To answer the heart of your question: You *do* need an SMTP server. You can set one up locally, or use a remote server.

*Which* SMTP service to use and *how* to set up a server is too broad of a question for this community -- You'll have to do some research and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: what smtp server do you use?

Comment: im not really trying to make the question complicated. i just wanted to be able to send emails without using localhost. is there any well known stmp server that can integrate with python sendmail func?

Comment: I understand, though that question *is* unfortunately complicated. The SMTP server you should use depends on your needs. You can use a free service like [Google's SMTP Service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server) if you want to get started, though it's rather limited at a glance.

Comment: I forgot you've already tried Google's service. [Fortunately, there are others available.](https://www.mailjet.com/feature/smtp-relay/)